# Select a value from a nested hash with unknown keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that looks something like this:

```
hash = { "data" => {
    "Aatrox" => {
        "id" => "Aatrox",
        "key" => "266",
        "name" => "Aatrox"
        },
    "Ahri" => {
        "id" => "Ahri",
        "key" => "123",
        "name" => "Ahri"
        },
    "Another name" => {
        "id" => "Another name",
        "key" => "12",
        "name" => "Another name"
        },
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get the value from "id" that matches a given key:

```
def get_champion_name_from_id(key)
    filtered = @champion_data["data"].select do | key, champ_data |
        Integer(champ_data["key"]) == key
    end     
end
```

I'm using select to get the items that match the block, however, the return value is another hash that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "Aatrox": {
        "id" => "Aatrox",
        "key" => "266",
        "name" => "Aatrox"
    } 
}
```

How can I avoid this and get just the last nested hash? 
If the key passed was 266, I want to get this hash:

```
{
    "id" => "Aatrox",
    "key" => "266",
    "name" => "Aatrox"
}
```

This hash is the result of a parsed JSON file, so there's no way I can do `filtered["Aatrox"]` to get a given value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values) returns values only (without keys). And by using [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), you will get the first matched item instead of an array that contains a single item.

```
@champion_data['data'].values.find { |champ_data|
  champ_data['key'] == '266'
}
# => {"id"=>"Aatrox", "key"=>"266", "name"=>"Aatrox"}
```

---

```
def get_champion_name_from_id(key)
  key = key.to_s
  @champion_data['data'].values.find { |champ_data|
    champ_data['key'] == key
  }
end
```

Comment: This is great, much cleaner than what I was trying, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `select` method also:

```
@champion_data["data"].select do |key, val|
  @champion_data["data"][key] if @champion_data["data"][key]["key"] == "266"
end
```

Comment: This returns the same result, another nested hash, which is not what I'm looking for